# I had an error when I ran my program while using Shared_Preferences Flutter

Tags: flutter, android-studio, dart

I wanted to use the latest version of Shared Preferences but when I ran pub get, it creates some error so I downgraded the plugin and the up b get works successfully but when I ran my app, this is what it said.

```
Launching lib\main.dart on INE LX2 in debug mode...
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...
../../AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/shared_preferences-0.5.12+4/lib/shared_preferences.dart:14:8: Error: Error when reading '../../AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/shared_preferences_windows-0.0.2+3/lib/shared_preferences_windows.dart': The system cannot find the path specified.

import 'package:shared_preferences_windows/shared_preferences_windows.dart';
       ^
../../AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/shared_preferences-0.5.12+4/lib/shared_preferences.dart:40:53: Error: Method not found: 'SharedPreferencesWindows'.
          SharedPreferencesStorePlatform.instance = SharedPreferencesWindows();
                                                    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^


FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Script 'C:\Users\me\flutter\packages\flutter_tools\gradle\flutter.gradle' line: 1035

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:compileFlutterBuildDebug'.
> Process 'command 'C:\Users\me\flutter\bin\flutter.bat'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 2m 57s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
```

This is my pubspec.yaml dependency:

```
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  carousel_slider: ^2.3.1
  assets_audio_player: ^2.0.13+1
  hive: ^1.4.4+1
  path_provider: ^1.6.27
  hive_flutter: ^0.3.1
  flip_card: ^0.4.4
  speech_recognition: ^0.3.0+1
  easy_localization: ^2.1.0
  translator: ^0.1.2
  permission_handler: ^3.1.0
  swipedetector: ^1.2.0
  shared_preferences: ^0.5.7+3
```

I used this plugin because I saw one problem that tackles this problem in another Stack overflow. But still it did not solve the problem.

I first use shared_preferences version 0.5.10 and I had the same error so I downgraded to ver 0.5.7+3 and I still have this error. What should I do? If ever you need additional info please let me know, thank you.

Comment: please try again after running this command "flutter clean"

Comment: Ill try. Please wait for the response thank you

Comment: Still the same error